# Transform IEnumerable<Dto> to IEnumerable<ViewModel>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my action I am returning an `IEnumerable<Dto>`, but due to some changes in the logic, I want to return an `IEnumerable<ViewModel>`. The main difference between `Dto` and `ViewModel` are just two fields.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetRecursos(Guid LeccionId)
{
    var result = _IProfesorRecurso.GetRecursoFromLeccion(LeccionId);
    if (result == null) return BadRequest();  
    return result;
}
```

The result is the `IEnumerable<Dto>`:

```
 public class Dto
 {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    /* here are some properties */
 }
```

The `ViewModel` would be this:

```
public class viewmodel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    /* here are some properties, the same as in Dto */
    public string ViewmodelProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"in my action I am returning an IEnumerable, but due to some changes in the logic, I want to return an IEnumerable"* -- can you clarify that sentence?

Comment: Which collection you want to convert ?

Comment: I corrected it but it seems there is a bug that does not allow me to use < >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `result` is a collection of your dto classes, you can use a LINQ query and use the `Select` method to generate a new list of your view model class

```
var newList = result.Select(x=>new MyViewModel { Id =x.Id, 
                                                 Name=x.Name,
                                                 ExtraProperty = "New property on vm"});
```

This is basically same as using a `foreach` loop to go through the result collection and create a new MyViewModel object

```
var newList = new List<MyViewModel>();
foreach(var d in result)
{
   var vm = new MyViewModel  { Id=d.Id, Name =d.Name};
   vm.SomeOtherProperty = d.SomeOtherProperty;
   vm.ExtraProperty = "New property on vm";
   newList.Add(vm);
}
```